# flutter ios release size is way larger than apk release

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to release my flutter app and I encountered this problem where the release size of ios app is too large. The apk release size is about 21.4 MB and the ios release size is about 480 MB!! I don't know what is the problem I tried to update flutter and flutter clean but nothing has changed.

These are my dependencies in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  intl: ^0.16.1
  provider: ^4.1.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  chips_choice: ^1.2.0
  cached_network_image:
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  url_launcher: ^5.5.0
  dotted_border: ^1.0.6
  timeago: ^2.0.26
  flutter_rating_bar: ^3.0.1+1
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.5
```

and the my assets file (images and fonts) is about 1.4 MB.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

First run "flutter clean" in the terminal, then try to release the apk. Normally it is bigger but flutter clean can reduce more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`--release` flag help you to delete log file from fat APK. try to use following command:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

and For Android,

check to **build->apps->output->apk**
Make sure you running android emulator.

For iOS,

```
flutter build ios --release
```

But you required **valid profile certificate**

Reference [document](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk)

Comment: I already did this but the size is so large for the ios app, 480, while the apk 21.4

Comment: As per my understanding , By default, the app bundle contains your dart code and the Flutter runtime compiled for armeabi-v7a (ARM 32-bit), arm64-v8a (ARM 64-bit), and x86-64 (x86 64-bit).thats why the size multiplied.

Comment: isn't for android?